# BufferedReader не читает последнюю строку ввода из консоли

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Не могу корректно ввести текст в консоль, так как последняя строка (даже когда она единственная) никогда не будет прочитана.

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    .lines()
    .flatMap(s -> s.lines())
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу передать N количество строк в консоль и работать с ними, ввод строк осуществляется с помощью Ctrl+D. Если прекратить ввод строк не переходя на новую строку, то последняя строка не считается, и если строка одна и так выполнить Ctrl+D, то она тоже не считается.

Comment: Вот это `.flatMap(s -> s.lines())` для чего? Если этот вызов убрать, то какое наблюдается поведение?

Comment: Проблема в вызове .lines() он обрабатывает строки оканчивающиеся символом новой строки т.к. ваша последняя строка не оканчивается таким символом, то она и не считывается, если после .lines() добавить .map(s -> s + System.lineSeparator()), то последняя строка считается

Если залезть в исходнике BufferedReader, то там будет следующее
 /* Skip a leftover '\n', if necessary */
            if (omitLF && (cb[nextChar] == '\n'))
                nextChar++;
            skipLF = false;
            omitLF = false;